# Laravel 5.8 isAdmin Gate?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm learning how to use the Gate and @can stuff

in my AuthServiceProvider I have

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    $this->registerPostPolicies();
}

public function registerPostPolicies()
{
    Gate::define('isAdmin', function($user) {
        return $user->roles->where('title', 'like', '%' . 'Admin')->count();
    });
}
```

and in my blade I have

```
...
            @can('isAdmin')
                <a aria-disabled="false" href="{{ route('admin.home')}}" target="_self" class="dropdown-item" role="menuitem" ><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Admin Menu</a>  
            @endcan 
...
```

For roles I have

```
| id | title       | 
+----+-------------+-
|  1 | Admin       | 
|  2 | User        | 
|  3 | Group Admin | 
|  4 | Site Admin  | 
+----+-------------+-
```

Which is why the like %Admin query...

but what I am finding is that the gate doesn't seem to work.. it simply blocks everyone.. I want to enable the Admin menu for anyone with a role title that has Admin in it..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `$user->roles()` with brackets instead to indicate you are querying from database.

```
return $user->roles()->where('title', 'like', '%' . 'Admin')->count();
```

Without (), it has become Collection and you cannot use LIKE with where() when filtering a collection. Refer [Collections - Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-where)

Comment: its always the little things.... - though should the return be made to be a boolean? or is it ok to be a number == true, error ==false?

Comment: No need if you want to keep it simple. 0 would always meant false. Other number would meant true.